# Add "active" class to topmenu, magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to add active class to my topmenu. And i already saw a bunch of subjects on forums, but i didn't saw code like i have. Can you please hepl me. I tried to "echo $currentUrl" but this what i saw " localhost.com/app/etc/local.xml "

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>

<?php if($_menu): ?>

<?php
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();

$locale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();

$_topMenuItems['ru_RU'] = array(
    /*$this->__('Home') => $baseUrl,*/
    $this->__('IIW, Delivery and payment') => $baseUrl . 'dostavka-oplata.html',
    $this->__('IIW, About us') => $baseUrl . 'pro-nas-kategorija.html',
    $this->__('IIW, Partners') => $baseUrl . 'partneram.html',
    $this->__('IIW, Contacts') => $baseUrl . 'contacts',
    $this->__('IIW, It is interesting') => $baseUrl . 'korisna-informacija.html',
    /* $this->__('IIW, Where to buy') => $baseUrl . 'de-prudbatu.html', */
);
?>

<nav id="nav">
    <ol class="nav-primary">
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        $length = count($_topMenuItems[$locale]);
        foreach ($_topMenuItems[$locale] as $label => $_itemUrl) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                echo $_menu;
            }

            $customMenuClass = ' cm-' . ($i + 1);

            if ($i == 0) {
                $customMenuClass .= ' first';
            } elseif ($i == ($length - 1)) {
                $customMenuClass .= ' last';
            }
            if (trim($currentUrl, '/') == trim($_itemUrl, '/')) {
                $customMenuClass .= ' active';
            }
            ?>

            <li class="level0<?php echo $customMenuClass ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_itemUrl ?>" class="level0 "><?php echo $label ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var locationUrl = location.href;
$(".yourmenu a.yourclass").each(function() {
  var menuLinkHref = $(this).attr("href");
  if (~locationUrl.indexOf(menuLinkHref)) {
   $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
});
</script>
```

JS solution if you need
.yourmenu - class of the menu, where your links must change class .actve;
.yourclass - class allready used for each link in the menu (ex.".menu_item_link").

Comment: Thanks, I have completed your code for my needs and changed `$(this).addClass("active");` to `$(this).closest('li').addClass("active");` .